# Does $\mathbb{CP}^2$ admit a Riemann surface lamination structure?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry, foliations

Does $\mathbb{CP}^2$ admit a Riemann surface lamination structure?  Every paper or article I looked at, talk only about singular laminations on $\mathbb{CP}^2$.  I was wondering why.  If you know something about it or you can give some reference, it would be nice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is conjectured that $\mathbb {CP}^2$ contains no embedded compact laminated set (without singularities) apart the smooth algebraic curves.

This is a strong form of the "Minimal Exceptional" conjecture, stating that for a singular holomorphic foliation of $\mathbb{CP}^2$, every leaf accumulates in the singular set.

Nice references about this subject are the following surveys:

- É. Ghys - *Laminations par surfaces de Riemann*. Dynamique et géométrie complexes -
  Panor. Synthèses, 8, 1999.
- S. Zakeri - *Dynamics of singular holomorphic foliations on the complex projective plane*. Laminations and foliations in dynamics, geometry and topology -
  Contemp. Math., 269, Amer. Math. Soc., 2001.
- J. E. Fornaess and N. Sibony - *Riemann surface laminations with singularities*. - J. Geom. Anal. 18 (2008), no. 2, 400–442.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please give the name of the articles.  I guess you are talking about Riemann surface laminations by Ghys and Dynamics of \mathbb{P}^2 : examples by Fornaess and Sibony.  I couldn't find the article by Zakeri.

Comment: Dear @DivakaranDivakaran ,  I added more details about the references. I hope it helps.